# Unpin all fixed nodes

Tags: d3.js

How do I unpin all nodes that have been fixed whenever any of the fixed nodes is double-clicked (rather than just the one double clicked)?

I've tried the brute force method by using:

```
svg.selectAll(".node").classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
```

or

```
svg.selectAll(".node").classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
```

Both methods will unpin the double clicked node - but not the others.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `d` you are accessing is only set false in the single case. This is one way to remove the `fixed` class from all nodes currently marked `fixed`.

```
svg.selectAll(".node .fixed").classed("fixed", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

After more trial and error I've found that:

```
svg.selectAll(".node").classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
```

will unpin the double clicked node and restore all pinned nodes back to their default color but the rest of pinned nodes remain pinned.

```
force.nodes().forEach(function(d) { d.fixed = false; });
```

will unpin all pinned (fixed) nodes - but will not restore the default color.

So my strategy is to use both to unpin all nodes and restore all nodes to the default color.